# How to grant EKEventstore access to a Mac command line tool

Tags: macos, command-line, calendar

I'm unable to access the EKEventstore on a Mac using a command line tool. The code works fine when used in a simple Cocoa App, but not in the command line. The following code leads to access error messages and programs termination.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let status =  EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
print(status)
```

Adding an Info.plist, with the appropriate private keys does not help and sandboxing seems to be no option in Xcode for command line apps. I'm running Xcode 10.1 on Mojave 10.14.5

Has anyone found a solution to access the Mac Calendar by a command line app?